# Multiple recipient for salesforce and Carbon copies

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Hi guys am currently trying to add 2 recipient to my doc

- ROUTINGORDER - 1 should be the first signer
- ROUTINGORDER - 2 should be the second signer

but am having this error while adding the second recipient

> Error: Problem: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed:
>   WebService returned a SOAP Fault: One or both of Username and Password
>   are invalid. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=missing in Web.Config

and do you know how to add Carbon Copies also

Please find below the code

```
The recipient Signer
    DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient.Email = signer_email;
    recipient.UserName = signer_name;
    recipient.ID = 1;
    recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
    recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
    recipient.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientCaptiveInfo();
    recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;

The recipient Signer  tab 
    DocuSignAPI.Tab signHereTab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    signHereTab.Type_x = 'SignHere';
    signHereTab.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    signHereTab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'signer1sig'; // Anchored for doc 1
    signHereTab.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 8;
    signHereTab.RecipientID = 1;
    signHereTab.Name = 'Please sign here';
    signHereTab.ScaleValue = 1;
    signHereTab.TabLabel = 'signer1sig';

The recipient  User2
    DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient1= new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient1.Email = User2;
    recipient1.UserName = User2;
    recipient1.ID = 2;
    recipient1.Type_x = 'Signer';
    recipient1.RoutingOrder = 2;
    recipient1.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientCaptiveInfo();

    recipient1.RequireIDLookup = false;   


The recipient  User2 tab 
    DocuSignAPI.Tab signHereTab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    signHereTab1 .Type_x = 'SignHere';
    signHereTab1 .AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    signHereTab1 .AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = 'signer2sig'; 
    signHereTab1 .AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 8;
    signHereTab1 .RecipientID = 2;
    signHereTab1 .Name = 'Please sign here ';
    signHereTab1 .ScaleValue = 1;



    DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
    envelope.Subject = subject;  
    envelope.AccountId = account_id;
    envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
    envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[2];
    envelope.Tabs.Tab.add(signHereTab);
    envelope.Tabs.Tab.add(signHereTab1 );
    envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient();
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[2];
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient.add(recipient);
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient.add(recipient1);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!! cheers

Comment: This is just a code to add recipient details, where is the code to create complete envelope and call the docuSign end point? Error is saying that you can are calling DS API with wrong username or password, can you please check if username and password are correct by logging into DS WebApp first.

Comment: Hello Amit K Bist

I have updates the code call you please have a look

Thanks in advance

Comment: When i have only 1 recipient i don't have this error when i have two recipient then i got this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check an example here at https://github.com/docusign/sfdc-recipe-hello-world, your code is throwing error as username password error, I am not sure from above code that all settings you have done correctly or not. So check the git example for reference.